# Getting "array_record_module" ImportError: dlopen in Tensor Flow Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-lite

i am trying to run following tensorflow code below which is mentioned in following example(https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker)

```
from tflite_model_maker import image_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader

# Load input data specific to an on-device ML app.
data = DataLoader.from_folder('flower_photos/')
train_data, test_data = data.split(0.9)

# Customize the TensorFlow model.
model = image_classifier.create(train_data)

# Evaluate the model.
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_data)

# Export to Tensorflow Lite model and label file in `export_dir`.
model.export(export_dir='/tmp/')
```

**But i am getting error as below**

```
2023-05-14 13:43:07.639151: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_addons/utils/tfa_eol_msg.py:23: UserWarning: 

TensorFlow Addons (TFA) has ended development and introduction of new features.
TFA has entered a minimal maintenance and release mode until a planned end of life in May 2024.
Please modify downstream libraries to take dependencies from other repositories in our TensorFlow community (e.g. Keras, Keras-CV, and Keras-NLP). 

For more information see: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2807 

  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/Documents/modelmakersrc/maketflitemodel.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tflite_model_maker/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tflite_model_maker import audio_classifier
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tflite_model_maker/audio_classifier/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.data_util.audio_dataloader import DataLoader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/audio_dataloader.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.task.model_spec import audio_spec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/model_spec/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.task.model_spec import text_spec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/model_spec/text_spec.py", line 44, in <module>
    from official.nlp.data import classifier_data_lib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/official/nlp/data/classifier_data_lib.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import tensorflow_datasets.core.logging as _tfds_logging
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core import community
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/community/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core.community.huggingface_wrapper import mock_builtin_to_use_gfile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/community/huggingface_wrapper.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_builder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_builder.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_info.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core import file_adapters
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/file_adapters.py", line 29, in <module>
    from array_record.python import array_record_module
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so, 0x0002): tried: '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/array_record/python/array_record_module.so' (not a mach-o file)
```

Following installed pip packages

Package                      Version

---

absl-py                      1.4.0
array-record                 0.2.0
astunparse                   1.6.3
attrs                        23.1.0
Automat                      22.10.0
boltons                      23.0.0
brotlipy                     0.7.0
cachetools                   5.3.0
certifi                      2023.5.7
cffi                         1.15.1
charset-normalizer           2.0.4
click                        8.1.3
conda                        23.3.1
conda-content-trust          0.1.3
conda-package-handling       2.0.2
conda_package_streaming      0.7.0
constantly                   15.1.0
construct                    2.10.68
cryptography                 39.0.1
dm-tree                      0.1.8
etils                        1.3.0
flatbuffers                  23.5.9
gast                         0.4.0
google-auth                  2.18.0
google-auth-oauthlib         1.0.0
google-pasta                 0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos     1.59.0
grpcio                       1.54.2
h5py                         3.8.0
hyperlink                    21.0.0
idna                         3.4
importlib-resources          5.12.0
incremental                  22.10.0
jax                          0.4.10
jsonpatch                    1.32
jsonpointer                  2.1
keras                        2.12.0
Keras-Preprocessing          1.1.2
libclang                     16.0.0
Markdown                     3.4.3
MarkupSafe                   2.1.2
ml-dtypes                    0.1.0
numpy                        1.23.5
oauthlib                     3.2.2
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
packaging                    23.0
pip                          23.1.2
pluggy                       1.0.0
ply                          3.11
promise                      2.3
protobuf                     4.23.0
psutil                       5.9.5
pyasn1                       0.5.0
pyasn1-modules               0.3.0
pybind11                     2.10.4
pycosat                      0.6.4
pycparser                    2.21
pycryptodomex                3.17
pyOpenSSL                    23.0.0
pysmi                        0.3.4
pysnmp                       4.4.12
PySocks                      1.7.1
PyYAML                       6.0
requests                     2.28.1
requests-oauthlib            1.3.1
rsa                          4.9
ruamel.yaml                  0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib             0.2.6
scipy                        1.10.1
setuptools                   65.6.3
six                          1.16.0
tensor                       0.3.6
tensorboard                  2.12.3
tensorboard-data-server      0.7.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.12.0
tensorflow-datasets          4.9.1
tensorflow-estimator         2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.32.0
tensorflow-metadata          1.13.1
termcolor                    2.3.0
tflite-support               0.1.0a1
toml                         0.10.2
toolz                        0.12.0
tqdm                         4.65.0
Twisted                      22.10.0
typeguard                    2.13.3
typing_extensions            4.5.0
urllib3                      1.26.15
Werkzeug                     2.3.4
wheel                        0.38.4
wrapt                        1.14.1
zipp                         3.15.0
zope.interface               6.0
zstandard                    0.19.0

i have tried all steps mentioned in the following site(https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker) but i am getting above erros.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/717724

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade my version of tensorflow-datasets. Per [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/4852)

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-datasets==4.9.1
```

Later I also had issues that required I downgrade tensorflow.

```
pip uninstall -y tensorflow && pip install -q tensorflow==2.8.0
```

Hope this helps!